# Detecting Unity Button Being Held Down And Not Just Pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I'm trying to make my unity game go from movement using the keyboard to movement using onscreen ui buttons. I used the built in ui buttons in unity, linked the button to the object I'm trying to move, and had it trigger a section of a script to move the object. The problem is it only detects the input of pressing the button at first, how do you detect the button being held down?

Answer (score 1):

You can check button being held down by check when button is released

First add the Event Trigger component to your button, add two event `PointerDown` and `PointerUp`, then set a bool to true on `PointerDown`, and false on `PointerUp`, that bool is whether button being held down, e.g:

```
 public class CheckHeldDown : Monobehaviour
 {
     public bool isHeldDown = false;
 
     public void onPress ()
     {
         isHeldDown = true;
         Debug.Log(isHeldDown);
     }
 
     public void onRelease ()
     {
         isHeldDown = false;
         Debug.Log(isHeldDown);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to build your game on mobile, you can Detect it with the amount of touches. For example this is some code I just used to make a Nitro button in a racing game:

```
public class NitroButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool pushed;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount >= 2)
        {
            pushed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pushed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This also allows for two finger pushes and such.